# how to get the results of this class in console.log?

Tags: javascript

How to get the results "_pathsArr (including the mid id), bestPath and amounts_out" in console.log?

Basically i need the arrPaths including their id and the amount_out of each.

Also i need to know where to input manually the amount_in for temporary tests.

Thanks.

This is my code:

```
    import { toFixed, accDiv } from './public';
// import Worker from './worker'
// import VueWorker from 'vue-worker'
class swapRouter {
  constructor() {
    this.markets = [];
    this.pair_market_map = {};
    this.mid_market_map = {};
    this.tokens = [];
    this.paths = [];
    this.isInit = false;
    this._pathsArr = [];
    this.bestPath = '';
  }
  init(data, vThis) {
    this.markets = data || [];
    this._pathsArr = [];
    this.bestPath = '';
    if (this.paths.length) {
      return
    }
    if (window.Worker) {
      this.workerToInitPath(vThis)
    } else {
      this.initPath()
    }
  }

  workerToInitPath(vThis) {
    
HERE GOES THE CODE THAT FINDS THE PATHS AND AMOUNTS_OUT

}
 const d = [{ here are the data correctly organized }

const swapRouter1 = new swapRouter()
 swapRouter1.init(d)
console.log(swapRouter1);
```

Is this correctly declared?

```
this.bestPath = '';
```

Or must be:

```
this.bestPath = [];
```

Because get only markets, tokens and paths in the result (console.log), but don't get_pathsArr and bestPath.

I also need that the path results includes the "mid" (the id number).

Comment: Hi ! This is a lot of code for such a small question. Can you create a working snippet with the `<>` button so we can see the problem? Also read how to write a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Thank you for your recommendation, I'm new on stackoverflow. I've edited the code and the questions. I think now someone can understands it and give me an answer.  Practically I'm newbie in javascript and don't know the correct code to get the mentioned results.